# Populating rows in table with previous row value oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

```
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
| id | counter | name  | duties | remarks | monies |
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | jake  |        |         |        |
|  2 |       0 |       | clean  | misc    | 12k    |
|  3 |       1 | james |        |         |        |
|  4 |       0 |       | clean  | misc    | 12k    |
|  5 |       0 |       | soap   | misc    | 12k    |
|  6 |       0 |       | shower | misc    | 12k    |
|  7 |       1 | john  |        |         |        |
|  8 |       0 |       | dry    | misc    | 12k    |
|  9 |       0 |       | scrub  | misc    | 12k    |
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Here above the data is grouped by person then their duties are listed :

I need a way to get the data to look like this using oracle sql :

```
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
| id | counter | name  | duties | remarks | monies |
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | jake  |        |         |        |
|  2 |       0 | jake  | clean  | misc    | 12k    |
|  3 |       1 | james |        |         |        |
|  4 |       0 | james | clean  | misc    | 12k    |
|  5 |       0 | james | soap   | misc    | 12k    |
|  6 |       0 | james | shower | misc    | 12k    |
|  7 |       1 | john  |        |         |        |
|  8 |       0 | john  | dry    | misc    | 12k    |
|  9 |       0 | john  | scrub  | misc    | 12k    |
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
```

having a bit of trouble iterating over every row... dont mind if its plsql - sql prefered tho

Tried a few things... but it goes back to null  after the 2nd row for each person

Comment: I havent the faiintest clue how to format the tables to make them look good...please any who knows please format them and post how to

Comment: oh my goodness Gordon Linoff I own your book! sql and excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select coalesce(name, lag(name ignore nulls) over (order by id)),
       . . .
from t;
```

This is fetching the previous non-`NULL` value from the `name` columns, where "previous" is based on the ordering of the `id` column.